# Kiali can't see any topo of my services in the Graph view

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm running kubernetes v1.7.10, and Istio 1.0.4, and also, kiali v0.9, which bundled with istio 1.0.4.

Then I deployed bookinfo example into a namespace, gateway points to the bookinfo service, and accessed the productpage homepage from a browser, all were fine.

But, from Graph view of kiali, just a diamon icon with label "unknown" displayed. what's wrong with it?

I can see all the services, workloads, istio configs on the Kiali, just no topology.

At last,  I traced back to the prometheus metrics, something like:

```
istio_requests_total{connection_security_policy="none",destination_app="unknown",destination_principal="unknown",destination_service="details.test.svc.cluster.local",destination_service_name="details",destination_service_namespace="test",destination_version="unknown",destination_workload="unknown",destination_workload_namespace="unknown",instance="172.22.178.111:42422",job="istio-mesh",reporter="destination",request_protocol="http",response_code="200",source_app="unknown",source_principal="unknown",source_version="unknown",source_workload="unknown",source_workload_namespace="unknown"}
```

I noticed that they were all "unknown",  destination_app, destination_version, source_app, source_version ... , I believe that's why no topo displayed.

And the metrics from http://istio-telemetry:42422/metrics:

```
istio_requests_total{connection_security_policy="none",destination_app="unknown",destination_principal="unknown",destination_service="details.test.svc.cluster.local",destination_service_name="details",destination_service_namespace="test",destination_version="unknown",destination_workload="unknown",destination_workload_namespace="unknown",reporter="destination",request_protocol="http",response_code="200",source_app="unknown",source_principal="unknown",source_version="unknown",source_workload="unknown",source_workload_namespace="unknown"} 32
```

Then I did another testing, I setup a cluster of kubernetes v1.10.3, and installed istio 1.0.4 into it, deployed bookinfo examples, everything is fine, with a beatiful topo graph.

So, I doubt is there anyting different between the kubernetes versions that break the graph view of kiali?

Can someone give any hints?

thanks.

likun

Comment: SUGGESTION: It sounds like you're viewing the graph in a web page.  Display the same page in Chrome, with Chrome Developer Tools enabled.  Look at the "network" tab.  Then render the graph.  I'll bet you *might* see one or more "404: not found" HTTP errors.  Otherwise - as you suspect - it's a configuration error.

Comment: Thanks for input, I tried, no 404 found. Kiali get metrics from prometheus, while prometheus get metrics from mixer, mixer doesn't output correct data. I have updated my post to include the metrics from mixer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a clear information on Istio website, but I believe kubernetes below 1.9 isn't supported. This is kind of suggested in the install page for Minikube: https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/platform-setup/minikube/

Maybe you can try with an older version of Istio, but I wouldn't guarantee it's going to work either. You would also have to pick up an older version of Kiali.

Kiali builds its graph from labels in istio telemetry, so you're right to correlate with what you see in Prometheus. In particular, `source_app`, `source_workload`, `destination_app` and `destination_workload` are used by Kiali to detect graph relations.

Comment: As far as I know, we need k8s 1.9 to support sidecar auto injection, and validating webhook ?